# Image data not sending properly - Ajax, Cordova

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cordova

The following code is to take picture and send to server using ajax, but the image data not properly send.

```
 <script>
      var pictureSource;   // picture source
      var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 
      var image = "";


  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {

        function alertDismissed() {
        };
            pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
            destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
        }

 function capturePhoto() {
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
                quality: 50,
                destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL
            });
        }

            function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {

            var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

            smallImage.style.display = 'block';

            smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

            image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

            alert("Image = "+image);
        }

     function onFail(message) {
            alert('Failed because: ' + message);
        }

    function submitFunction() {

        function alertDismissed() {
        };

        var dataString = 'image='+image;

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "url.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){

        }
        });

        }
        </script>

        <input type="button" id="camera" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" value="Take Photo"  onclick="capturePhoto();"/>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" value="Next"  onclick="submitFunction();" />

        <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
```

The image is displaying properly, and alert shows "Image =  data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDABALDA4M......o7cUAPFJR9KWmgP/9k=".

But, in the following php, the $_POST['image'] is not receiving the proper data, it missing somecharacters like '+' and also replacing it with space or new line. So, when I returning back from db in other page, image not displayed properly.

url.php

```
$con=mysql_connect('server','user','password') or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

$db=mysql_select_db('db',$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 

$retval = mysql_query( "UPDATE tablename SET photo='".$_POST['image']."' WHERE ID='".$_POST['id']."'", $con );

echo $_POST['image'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your base64 image string would contain characters with special meaning in url encoding, you need to encode them

```
var dataString = 'image='+encodeURIComponent(image);
```

or easier

```
data: {"image":image},
```

Comment: `var dataString = 'image='+encodeURIComponent(image);`


Works fine and the data uploaded properly. I am trying to display the image in other page is not working.


It returns only "data:image/jpeg;base64".

Comment: <script>
var dataString = 'id='+id;
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "get.php",
  data: dataString,
  cache: false,
  success: function(result){   document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "<img src=\""+result+"\">";}});
</script>
In php,
$photo = "";
$retval = mysql_query( "SELECT photo FROM tablename WHERE ID='".$_POST['id']."'", $con );
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
 $photo = $row['photo'];
     
echo $photo;

Comment: I am sorry, I was editing a wrong file. Image displaying properly. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

i give you my code thats works great for me.

Before using it in the app following is very important to work:
you use cordova/phonegap camera plugin : cordova-plugin-camera

so you have to set the option by capturing the image following the get base64 encoded image

```
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
```

the function onPhotoDataSuccess

```
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
    upladImage(imageData);
}
```

the function uploadImage

```
function upladImage(imageData){
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/upload/up.php",
        data: {img_data:imageData},
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        success: function (result) {
        alert("upload OK: "+ result);
        }

    });
}
```

img_data is the $_POST[img_data] variable on the server side

PHP  code On server side (simple code)

```
#from ajax post request save the post variable to $img
$img = $_POST["img_data"];

#folder to upload chmod 777 !!!
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'images/');

#filename will be generated by timestamp 
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . time() . '.jpg'; 

#replace data header
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);

#replace empty space
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img); 

#base64 decode
$data = base64_decode($img);

#save the file
$success = file_put_contents($file,$data);

#give feedback to your APP
if($success)
    echo "upload successfully";
else
    echo "an error occours while saving file";
```

the ajax post request method is a good alternative to file transfer plugin upload function because some android version have problem with the file transfer upload function. (so it was my experience)

also important: you have to include cordova and jquery library in your html file.